# c++ double dispatch observer notification

Tags: c++, interface, observer-pattern, double-dispatch

Here is the code I am currently troubleshooting:

```
void CTimer::notify()
{
    std::vector<IObserver*>::iterator it;
    for(it=observers.begin();it!=observers.end();++it)
    {
        ITimerNotification* notification = new CTimerNotification(now());
        (*it)->readNotification(*notification);
    }
}

class CTimerNotification : public ITimerNotification
{
    public:
        CTimerNotification(const timeval& t)
        {
            time = t;
        }
    protected:
        timeval time;
    private:
        virtual ~CTimerNotification();
        virtual void read(const IObserver& o) const
        {
            o.update(*this);
        }
        virtual const timeval& getTime() const
        {
            return time;
        }
};

class IObserver
{
    public:
        virtual ~IObserver();
        virtual void readNotification(const INotification&) const=0;
        virtual void update(const INotification&) const=0;
};

class ITimerObserver : public IObserver
{
    public:
        virtual void update(const ITimerNotification&) const=0;
};

class TestObserver : public ITimerObserver
{
    public:
        virtual void readNotification(const INotification& n) const
        {
            n.read(*this);
        }
        virtual void update(const INotification& n) const
        {
            std::cout<<"???: TestObserver: update()!\n";
        }
        virtual void update(const ITimerNotification& n) const
        {
            std::cout<< n.getTime().tv_sec << "." << n.getTime().tv_usec <<": TestObserver: update()!\n";
        }
};
```

So the code runs, `CTimer::notify()` gets called, which creates a `TimerNotification` and passes it to the observer via `readNotification()` which in turn calls the notification's `read()` method, which finally calls the observer's (hopefully) correct `update()` method.

The last step is what fails. It calls the `update(INotification&)` method instead of the desired `update(ITimerNotification&)` method.

What am I missing here for this attempted Double Dispatch pattern to work? It does not appear to be getting the correct type information to select the appropriate function call.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: We need to see `IObserver`. I suspect that it doesn't have a `virtual void update(const ITimerNotification& n)`.

Comment: Edited. IObserver does not, but ITimerObserver, which the TestObserver implements, does. Is this the problem?

Comment: I hope it's not your real `CTimer::notify` function, or you have a memory leak. Since you pass `notification` as a reference, why do you use `new` to allocate it in the first place? There's no need for `new` in the code you shown us.

Comment: I forgot the delete statement after the notification was sent. Whoops. Also I can never decide on whether I want to use references or pointers so I end up with things like that.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, that's the problem. Calling against `IObserver` only gives the methods visible in `IObserver`. The calling code doesn't implicitly "know" about subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CTimerNotification` needs a `read` something like this

```
virtual void read(const IObserver& o) const {
    ITimerObserver* to = dynamic_cast<ITimerObserver*>(&o);
    if (to) {
        to->update(*this);
    } else {
        o.update(*this);
    }
}
```

and you need a `using IObserver::update;` in `ITimerObserver`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! What does the `using IObserver::update;` do for the `ITimerObserver` interface?

Comment: Makes it so both versions of `update` are visible in `ITimerObserver`. Otherwise the new one you add, with `const ITimerNotification&` as an operand, hides the one declared in `IObserver`.